# Python - key error issue due to path structure?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am creating a script to train a tensorflow model and I am debugging as I go along .

This is the snippet of code where the error is raised.

```
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'car_parts/train',
    'car_parts/train',
    'car_parts/train',
    ['piston', 'turbo','wheel']
)
```

I have a folder called ***tensorflow*** , which contains the script and then I have two more folders inside called ***train*** and ***validate*** which contain my images and xml files.

It throws this exception when I debug `Exception has occurred: KeyError 'car_parts/train' File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\tensorflow\runTF.py", line 23, in <module> train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(`

I understand it's complaining that it can't find 'car_parts/train' but **how do I fix it**?

I've tried `r"C:\Users\x\Desktop\tensorflow\train"` as a location but still throws the same exception.

If I try also  `'C:/Users/x/Desktop/tensorflow/train'` I get the same exception .

If I try this

```
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'C:\Users\x\Desktop\tensorflow\train',
    'C:\Users\x\Desktop\tensorflow\train',
    'C:\Users\x\Desktop\tensorflow\train',
    ['piston', 'turbo','wheel']
)
```

Then it throws this `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

**What am I doing wrong here?**

**EDIT**

```
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'car_parts/train',
    'car_parts/train',
    
    ['piston', 'turbo','wheel']
)
```

If I do only two locations even though I want to pick up 3 objects it works fine and does not throw the error.

Here is how my folder structure looks.
\DESKTOP\CAR_PARTS

├───train

└───validate

Inside the train and validate folders , I have images with corresponding xml files in the PASCAL VOC format.

**Why can't I load in the data correctly ??**

Comment: Try them as `'C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\tensorflow\\train'`, backslash is a so called escape character (often used for encoding control characters, like `\n` is a new-line or `\t` is a tabulator), and in this particular case `\U` is misidentified as the beginning of a Unicode code point. Getting the exact same error with forward slashes sounds unlikely.

Comment: Nope `'C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\tensorflow\\train' ` throws the same error still.
Using forwards slashes does actually throw the same error although I can't figure why..

Comment: What are the arguments to `from_pascal_voc`? Looking at [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/DataLoader#from_pascal_voc) the first two arguments are paths wheras the third should be a list of strings (or dict)

Comment: Could you clarify what I should have added instead with an example? I can update the question to show my folder structure  
I thought that here `train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    'car_parts/train',
    'car_parts/train',
    
    ['piston', 'turbo','wheel']
) ` 
I would put the location of the images with my xml files and then in [ ] I would put my labels?